# Windows 8 People app without a delete option

Tags: windows-8, contacts, windows-8-people-app

I'm trying to delete contacts in my People app and when I right click, there isn't an option to delete.  Only pin to start or edit.  Where did it go?  How do I delete these contacts?

Comment: Are you right clicking on their name, or are you opening their entry first, and then right-clicking?

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I delete these contacts?

> **Delete contacts**
>
> You can only delete your Hotmail or Outlook contacts from the People
>   app. If you've connected other accounts like Google, or Skype, you'll
>   need to go to that app or website to delete those contacts.
>
> 1. On Start, tap or click People.
> 2. In the search box, enter the name of the contact whose info you want to delete. You'll see a list of contacts as you type—tap or click
>      the one you want.
> 3. Tap or click a contact.
> 4. Swipe in from the bottom edge to see the app commands.
>      (If you're using a mouse, right-click within the app.)
> 5. Tap or click Delete.

Source [People app help](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/people-app-faq)

Comment: I've already deleted from Google and don't use Skype.  These are contacts that were created within the app since I've had it.  Even the ones deleted from Google still show up.

Comment: You have to open the contact first. Please read the answer again and follow the steps carefully.

Comment: I've opened the contacts and the delete option still doesn't show up.  Some do but some don't and I can't figure out the link between the ones I can delete and the ones I can't.  Some tell you that you'll need to delete them somewhere else before they're gone and even after I've done that they still show up without the option to delete.